# Hide API key in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension, and I've been trying to decide on the best low-effort way to hide a 3rd party API key to avoid hardcoding it in the extension JS files.

Obfuscation, minifying, a lambda function that validates the Chrome extension ID... these are all security by obscurity and not bulletproof. I don't need bulletproof, but I still need something better. A dedicated proxy server to make the API calls on the extension's behalf, ain't it (too much effort for a low-complexity extension).

So here's an idea I'd like to validate: I am using Google authentication and Firebase (Firestore DB). The DB has rules to limit access to authenticated users. What if I save the API key in a new Firestore table and fetch it by querying the table through the authenticated user?

It's probably just as bad, right? The key will still be visible through the network tab as part of the response.... *sighs*.

Comment: I'll ask the obvious for the sake of the obvious, but why can't you hash the API key?

Comment: Hash where? On the client? How would that prevent key abuse if the hashing mechanism is in the client code?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Like I said, was asking for the obvious. Not much experience with extensions. I was thinking more in terms of REST.

Comment: Who are you hiding it from? A local user of the browser can always debug your code in devtools and find the key, so nothing you can do about it client-side. The only reliable way is to use the key on the server i.e. the extension will connect to your server, which will make the request and send the response back.

Comment: Right. So that’s what the question is about. Instead of setting up a server, would pulling it out of Firestore be bad practice? I’m hiding it from the browser user, correct.

Comment: Fetching the key from firebase will still make it visible for the user. You should rather use firebase functions as a proxu and never exposing the key to the browser

Comment: FB functions sound promising - will have a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to go down this route.. How about splitting the key and store them in 5 or 10 Firestore documents and join them on client side?

Comment: I mean sure but it sounds like extra effort for the same result, right? Eventually anything I do client-side is not obscured.

Comment: well it doesn't show up in network tab on its own so that'd be good enough for me

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I'll go the Firebase Cloud functions way. With the correct permissions in place, only Google-authenticated users can call the endpoint.